# Boost function with custom indexed string field does not work. Solr 3.6

Tags: solr, lucene, solr-boost

I'm improving an existing search system which is using Solr 3.6

I'm trying to boost search results using following function:

```
{!boost b=recip(sub(1,floor(strdist("someText",myField,jw))),1000000,1,1)}searchText
```

1. **searchText** - some text that user searches for;
2. **myField** - custom indexed document's field, value cam be empty or not empty string;

In short, this function divides by *1000001* scores of all search results where **myField**'s value is not equal to *someText*. In this way results with specified **myField**'s value are on top ordered by their original score.

Thus, the field is there, the value is present in the field, but the result's score is also divided and the result is somewhere deep down...

When I use:

```
fq=myField:[* TO *]
```

Solr filters out results where field's value is not empty string. So, it is recognized...

There is another legacy string field. When I apply my function using that field, everything works as it should. But when I use my field it fails.

Do you have any ideas of what might be wrong? What should I look for?

Please help. I've spent lots of time without success already, but I'm new to Solr and not able to resolve this issue so far...

Thank you!

Comment: What are the definitions for `myField` and the legacy field?

Comment: I've resolved my problem already and posted the answer. 
Thanks anyways! :)
Looks like you where having the same assumption.

Answer (score 0):

I've kept asking people, so, luckily, I've resolved my problem :)

So the problem was in the declaration of the field in **schema.xml**.
The *legacy field* was declared like this:

```
<field name="searchText" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
```

and *my field* was declared like this:

```
<field name="myField" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
```

And that's why my boost function did not work.
So I've changed to type **"string"** and everything works OK now :)